# Dockerfile command not working in build, but works in shell

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

After building my docker image (successfully), I am unable to use a tool that I intended to `make`. The strange thing is that when I delete the tool, re-extract the source and execute the **exact same command** inside a created container the tool is working just fine.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /code
COPY . .

# Install requirements.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Download and make trec_eval.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install wget -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential -y && \
    wget https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/releases/download/v9.0.7/trec_eval-9.0.7.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf trec_eval-9.0.7.tar.gz && \
    cd trec_eval-9.0.7 && make && cd ..

# Expose port.
EXPOSE 8050

# Start dashboard app.
CMD [ "python", "./run-comparator/app.py" ]
```

During build

```
Step 6/8 : CMD cd trec_eval-9.0.7 && make && cd ..
 ---> Running in 0663cc692bfe
Removing intermediate container 0663cc692bfe
 ---> 1cbdcbdc2d98
```

Using the tool without 're-making' (i.e. deleting folder, extracting, `make`)

```
root@451c1f6a2e0d:/code/trec_eval-9.0.7# ./trec_eval
bash: ./trec_eval: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

After 're-making' inside shell:

```
root@451c1f6a2e0d:/code# rm -rf trec_eval-9.0.7
root@451c1f6a2e0d:/code# tar -zxf trec_eval-9.0.7.tar.gz
root@451c1f6a2e0d:/code# cd trec_eval-9.0.7 && make && ..
```

It works as intended (gives correct usage instructions):

```
root@451c1f6a2e0d:/code/trec_eval-9.0.7# ./trec_eval
Usage: trec_eval [-h] [-q] {-m measure}* trec_rel_file trec_top_file
   -h: Give full help information, including other options
   -q: In addition to summary evaluation, give evaluation for each query
   -m: calculate and print measures indicated by 'measure'
       ('-m all_qrels' prints all qrels measures, '-m official' is default)
```

How can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: Is your question why the version you `make` outside docker, doesn't work inside docker, but `make` inside docker works inside docker?

Comment: When you call `make` outside the docker, it will compile it using the compiler to something that your OS + architecture can execute. There is no guarantee that it will work fine on another OS or another architecture, which is the case for docker. The correct way is to do `make` inside the new environment (docker).

Comment: I think you mean `RUN` instead of `CMD` in that line where you think you're building the trec_eval package. You already have a `CMD` at the bottom of the Dockerfile. That `CMD cd trec_eval-9.0.7 && make && cd ..` is a  no-op: it does nothing during build, and it gets overridden by the subsequent `CMD` so it does nothing at runtime.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the clarification about `CMD` and `RUN`. I have moved the `make` to the `RUN` command, yet the problem remains.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you've described: when I use the `Dockerfile` in your question to build an image, and start a shell in that image, the `trec_eval` commands runs without any errors.

Comment: @larsks Hm, I see.. when I remove the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` my errors disappear as well

Comment: What is in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @larsks https://filebin.net/mu7h0l6x7nhed4ya/requirements.txt?t=l8vc2t15

Comment: Still unable to reproduce. See my complete test [here](https://asciinema.org/a/AZzKrtbKtleajgWRCDfJbdtaC).

Comment: @larsks Thanks so much for your time! I still get the following error using your steps `bash: ./trec_eval: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, might come down to a MacOS - Docker thing?

I came accros [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error) seemingly relevant question. I can't apply it to my own situation though, any ideas?


```
root@23272124d42b:/code# file trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval
trec_eval-9.0.7/trec_eval: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|PIE>
```